# Divmod: Quotient and remainder of a division in one Elixir function

Tags: math, elixir

In many programming languages there is a combined operation that returns both the quotient and the remainder of a division as integers. In a lot of cases it is called `divmod` because it serves both the purposes of the division and the modulo function in one step.

I suppose the intention of having one operation is, that the division calculation doesn't need to be executed twice and that the results don't need to be represented as potentially lossy floating point values.

Is there such a combined function in Elixir? I can only find `div` and `rem` separately.

Comment: As far as I know, no there is no such function in Elixir.  I don't believe this is actually that common a feature in languages but I guess your experience of software development must differ from mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none is the language core library, but you might easily construct it yourself:

```rb
divmod =
  fn e, d ->
    ~w|div rem|a
    |> Enum.map(&apply(Kernel, &1, [e, d]))
    |> List.to_tuple()
  end
#⇒ #Function<12.99386804/2 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
divmod.(5, 2)
#⇒ {2, 1}
```

There are two possible reasons why it’s not presented in the standard library: a) `Elixir` ideology is to provide a scaffold, not the swiss-knife-framework and b) `Erlang` is not actually the best choice for doing math.

Comment: I know I can write it by myself. Your solution suffers from `rem`'s inability to work for negative numbers, which `mod` usually supports, though. Also, it probably does the calculation twice, or is there any obvious reason why this should not happen in your example?

Comment: FWIW, [here was a PR](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/4795) to add such a functionality to the Elixir core and it was rejected by the core team.

Answer (score 1):

```
  @doc """
    ## Parameters
      number - any integer/float
      divisor - what to divide by

    ## Returns
     {quotient, remainder}

    ## Example

  iex(6)> Data.divmod(12, 2)
  {6, 0}
  iex(7)> Data.divmod(12, 3)
  {4, 0}
  iex(8)> Data.divmod(12, 4)
  {3, 0}
  iex(9)> Data.divmod(12, 4.5)
  {2, 3.0}
  
  """
  def divmod(number, divisor) do
    result = number / divisor
    quotient = result |> Kernel.floor
    remainder = number - (quotient * divisor)
    {quotient, remainder}
  end
```